# SQL Server migration instance change to default instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, redirect, instance, alias

We have an old SQL Server instance `SERVER1\INS1` that was moved to a new SQL Server 2014 machine `SERVER2` using the default instance (old software doesn't support above 2014). `SERVER2` only has the default instance.

We have a ton of legacy apps with hardcoded queries that point to `SERVER1\INS1.DB1` that may (or may not) have the ability to rebuilt w/ the new server name. So we're hoping we can set up some sort of translation/aliasing to keep us from having to rebuild and redeploy these very old apps.

We have set up a DNS alias to point `SERVER1` to `SERVER2` and we have set up a x32 and x64 SQL Native Client aliases on `SERVER2` that list `SERVER1\INS1` as the alias name and `SERVER2` the server with the default 1433 port.

When I try to connect to the new server via SSMS using the alias `SERVER1`, it works. BUT when I try to connect using `SERVER1\INS1` I get a connection failure. Unfortunately, this is the reference that all the legacy apps are using.

Do I have to set up a `INS1` instance on the new server and redirect it to the default to get this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect one instance to another.  Your options are:

1. Install a new instance called INS1 and use that *instead of* the default instance.
2. Reconfigure the existing applications
3. Add SQL Server client aliases to each client redirecting SERVER1\INS1 to SERVER1 port 1433.

Comment: Thank you David ... I think we'll be trying #3 since the main app that is having this issue is actually a website, so I suspect we'd have to just add a SQL Server client alias on that web server. We'll give a sh